# Why "app.visible = False" can not make the excel app run backguound, but "app = xw.App(visible=False)" CAN?

Tags: python, xlwings

I installed the latest `xlwings` 3 days ago, for my Python3.6.0 32bit, on my Windows7 PC.
I want `xlwings` to work background, so I do like this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import xlwings as xw
import datetime

app = xw.apps.add()
app.visible = False

wb = app.books.open('catalog.xlsx')
sht = wb.sheets['Sheet1']
rg = sht.range('A1:B8')

time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
sht.range('A20').value = time

wb.save()
app.kill()
```

When I run it, my MS office 2010 window flashed and then disappeared.

I searched on stackoverflow, and got the solution. It can work well if I code this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import xlwings as xw

app = xw.App(visible=False)

wb = app.books.open('catalog.xlsx')    
sht = wb.sheets['Sheet1']
rg = sht.range('A1:B8')

time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
sht.range('A20').value = time

wb.save()
app.kill()
```

But WHY `app.visible = False` can not work well ?

If you can tell me the reason, I will say thanks to you in my heart. ^_^

Comment: And, I want to know, when a xlwings script is working, can we do some other excel work by hand, at the same time ?

Comment: Which version of `xlwings` are you using?

Comment: Latest Release: v0.11.5

Comment: sorry, it is in fact 0.11.7

Comment: I got it by "pip list" ^_^

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work well because when your code does this:

```
app = xw.apps.add()
app.visible = False
```

xlwings starts up the Office COM server *first* and *then* sets it to invisible. Which is why you see the flash.

When your code does this:

```
app = xw.App(visible=False)
```

xlwings starts up the Office COM server as invisible from the start.

Comment: OK, thanks. but I also want to know, when a xlwings script is working, can I do some other excel work by hand, at the same time ?

Comment: You can, but you need to be careful. If you have a modal dialogue box open (for example Format Cells), then COM updates to that workbook are likely to fail messily. It is hard to trap such failures because COM delivers VBA exceptions in a wrapper, not Python ones. A technique that I have found to be reasonably safe is to do the COM updates in workbook A, and do all other work in workbook B that gets values from A. Your screen will still flicker when the updates come through, though.